# Error while declaring ptr using calloc in global scope

Tags: c, scope, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc, global-scope

[cquery] type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
[cquery] redefinition of 'ptr' with a different type: 'int' vs 'int *

```
int *ptr,size=50;
ptr=(int*) calloc(size,sizeof(int));
```

How can i fix this error?Also what is the reason behind this.

Comment: You haven't really shown enough of your code for us to try to reproduce your problem. However if, as your title suggests, you have the `ptr=(int*) calloc(size,sizeof(int));` outside of *any* function, then that can't be done! Code that must execute **must** be inside a function (e.g. in `main`).

Comment: So do you mean that I cannot dynamically allocate a pointer in the global scope?

Comment: That is correct! You can (statically) initialize variables at the global scope but using `calloc` requires actual *execution* of code - must be in a function body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this

```
ptr=(int*) calloc(size,sizeof(int));
```

is not a declaration but an expression statement.

You may not place statements in a file scope.

Moreover a variable with the static storage duration (and file scope variables have the static storage duration) may be initialized with a compile-time constant.

So you should place the statement above in some function for example in main.

Also consider a possibility of redesigning your program such a way that it had as few file scope variables as possible.